# How to check if a translation item exists in Twig/Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, twig

Here is my macro for printing a sidebar item. Each `title` atttribute is build looking for `'tip.' ~ route` item in `messages.it.yml`.

Even if the **trans item does not exist** Twig always return the string passed to `trans` filter. For example:

```
tip:
    dashboard: Dashboard
```

Template:

```
{% _self.sideitem('dashboard', 'home') %} // <a title="Dashboard">...
{% _self.sideitem('fail', 'home') %}      // <a title="tip.fail">...

{% macro sideitem(route, icon) %}
    {% set active = (route == app.request.get('_route')) %}
    {% set icon = icon ? 'icon-' ~ icon ~ (active ? ' icon-white' : '') : '' %}

    <li class="{{ active ? 'active' : '' }}">
        <a href="{{ path(route) }}" title="{{ ('tip.' ~ route)|trans }}">
            <i class="{{ icon }}"></i> {{ ('nav.' ~ route)|trans }}
        </a>
    </li>
{% endmacro %}
```

***How can i check if a trans item exists before actually print it?***

**EDIT**: a brutal workaround could be (code not tested):

```
<li class="{{ active ? 'active' : '' }}">
    {% set look    = ('tip.' ~ route) %}
    {% set foreign = look|trans %}
    {% set has     = not(look == foreign) %}

    <a href="{{ path(route) }}" {{ not has ? '' : 'title="' ~ foreign ~ '"'  }} >
        <i class="{{ icon }}"></i> {{ ('nav.' ~ route)|trans }}
    </a>
 </li>
```

Comment: There is not such option natively. One possibility would be to check if the output of `('nav.' ~ route)|trans` is the same than `('nav.' ~ route)`.

Answer (score 17):

The solution I came up with was this one:

```
{% if "#{var}.something"|trans != "#{var}.something" %}
```

This just checks if the result of the translation key is different from the translation key itself. If a key has no translation, the "trans" filter returns the translation key.

Comment: This is only correct when using keys and not a default reference language.

Comment: Using this approach successfully for two years now. Slightly dirty but easy and readable. Plus: data for (possibly many) unwanted translations don't need to be maintained.

Answer (score 7):

You can use twig extension to confirm translation exists or not.

```
$locale = $translator->getLocale();
$catalogue = $translator->getCatalogue($locale);
$id = 'bank_transaction_history.transfer.' . $resultCode;
if ($catalogue->defines($id)) {
    return $translator->trans($id);
}
```

Comment: +1 This may be preferable to other approaches listed here since this won't triger profiler's translation errors. Note that you don't need the line `$locale = $translator->getLocale();`.   `getCatalog()` method's argument can stay null, in that case the method uses the instance's locale...

Comment: Also fixes the "translation exists but in another locale, so |trans will default to that another locale" problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've analyzed your problem and looked through the default Translator that is used in Symfony2.

It uses method [trans()](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Translation/Translator.html#method_trans) which is implemented like [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/Translator.php#L118).

For you the best workaround would be to redefine this method to return false, when you expect it.

Telling the long story short:

1. Write your class, that implements TranslatorInterface and extends
   Translator
2. Redefine method trans() there
3. Define service as a `translator` with your Class (it will replace
   default translator with yours)

That's it

I hope it helps ;)

Answer (score -1):

try to assign the string 'nav.' ~ route to the variable, and next translate the variable.