# How to say "if this translation is empty"

Tags: php, twig, symphony-cms

I want to have this image **not** showing if the translation is empty or non existing

```
<img class="partners-logo" src="{{ 'page.image.path' | trans | raw }}">
```

So can I wrap a logic loop around it as in the following code?

```
{% if {{ 'page.image.path' | trans }} is not null %}
    <img class="partners-logo" src="{{ 'page.image.path' | trans | raw }}">
{% endif %}
```

Obviously not right? Then how should it be?

Comment: You probably only need `{% if 'page.image.path'|trans %}` although I am not sure why `'page.image.path'` is quoted in your example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a translation item exists in Twig/Symfony2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638852/how-to-check-if-a-translation-item-exists-in-twig-symfony2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that :

```
{% if "page.image.path"|trans != "page.image.path" %}
```

This will check if the result of the translation is different from the translation key : if a translation key has no translation, filter `trans` returns the translation key.